# Where can I find a complete (!) list of all Hibernate events?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate supports several events through listener interfaces. I could find all interfaces in the [API docs](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/event/package-frame.html). But i couldn't find a complete list of the corresponding event names.
Any idea where to look?

Comment: look below the interfaces - there are the event classes.

Comment: I meant the names, like "flush-entity", "dirty-check", etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found it [here](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hibernate/core/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/event/EventListeners.java). Shame on Hibernate's documentation.