# How to run SQL SET statements against db at start of connection/session using Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, events

I'd like to send some SQL to the database at the start of the (database) session.

For example `SET TIME ZONE 'user-timezone'`, or set their client IP address to a custom variable (a "GUC" in postgres).

How can I automate this in Hibernate?

EclipseLink has a `postAcquireClientSession` event, but I don't see one with Hibernate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easier way to do this is to implement a custom org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider an example of which is provided [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18406.html) and override getConnection, so that it runs your SQL.

Other methods that are messier and may or may not work include using Integrators to setup Event Listeners, which listen at the wrong level and are listed in the following [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288487/where-can-i-find-a-complete-list-of-all-hibernate-events). Information on integrators is available from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#integrators).

Interceptors like Event Listeners also listen at the wrong level. An example of them is [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/interceptor/hibernate-interceptor-example/)

The other more complicated ways are subclassing the SessonFactory implementation to allow you to see a custom statistics provider which will then get called as part of the connectionOpened callback in JDBCContext if statistics are enabled.

Or alternatively you could subclass either the SessonFactory Implementation and JDBC context implementation or Session Implementation in order to customise the same connectionOpened callback to run your SQL.

Comment: is this something I should be doing in my connection pool rather than in hibernate? Thx

Comment: This is implementing a Connection Provider in order to have direct access to the initial database session. If you already are using a Custom ConnectionProvider in order to provide a custom connection pool to hibernate then you can add to it.

Answer (score 2):

this can be done via the hibernate session:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.prepareStatement("SET TIME ZONE 'user-timezone'").execute();
    }
});
```

This can be either be done with a utility method or applied selectively via a `@Before` aspect.

Comment: That is per Hibernate Session, not database session, as far as I know this will be called on the same database session multiple times for each Hibernate session instance.

Comment: I had to do some "SET SESSION..." on every INSERT, UPDATE,  DELETE operations. This helped :)