# How do I configure database connection per user account in Spring Data?

Tags: database, spring-data, spring-boot

We have a requirement that user account can provide username/password for database. This means that after user account is loaded, the user should use his own database connection for persistence.
How do I configure that in Spring Data?

Comment: For my understanding, why do you need that ?? You want do create other DataSource programmatically ? On the same schema ? Please, can you describe a little bit more your use case ?

Comment: Because we have this "secure deployment" requirement.

Comment: Maybe, but you're not responding my questions. What's your use case ? What's mean `secure deployment` in your particular context. It can mean a lot. And just to be sure, how do you authenticate a user ?

Comment: Customer requirement: Each user should connect to database using username/password. username/password is per user. Database credentials are not shared between users.

Comment: OK, and each user use the same schema. I mean, it should be the same url for your datasource. User are db user. And if a user with super privilege as root connect to your application, he will be able to drop your database. Otherwise, to use spring data, i think you should create yourself a new repository for each user and inject the user datasource, create the correct proxy on each repository, ...  Sorry to say that but a shell client for their database will be the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which database?

Which ORM implementation?

Spring has the [AbstractRoutingDataSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html), which lets you change the DataSource at runtime.

You could also use a delegation pattern, where the web server connects as a limited user, and then changes role to a different user if their authentication is successful. See [How to run SQL SET statements against db at start of connection/session using Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894945/how-to-run-sql-set-statements-against-db-at-start-of-connection-session-using-hi) and [Switch role after connecting to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database/19602050#19602050)

You'll probably need to disable caching in your ORM too.

Comment: I will use AbstractRoutingDataSource: http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/